# How to get VMWare to use native mouse position?

Tags: mouse, vmware-workstation

Is it possible to get VMWare to automatically grab focus when I move over the window of the virtual machine, and release focus when I leave, and use the same position for the mouse ponter, rather than a different position inside the VM?

I've tried to do this by installing VWare Tools inside the VM and having it running (icon in notification area), and by setting Edit -> Preferences -> Input

- Ungrab when cursor leaves window
- Hide cursor on grab
- Grab when cursor enters window

These setting don't seem to make any difference.  I'm using VMWare Workstation 6.05.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling VMWare Tools fixed it.

To uninstall: Go to Add/Remove Programs

To install:

1. In VMWare Workstation go to VM -> Install VmWare Tools...  This makes a virtual CD available to the VM.
2. Execute setup.exe on the CD.

Answer (score 0):

It should do this by default when the tools are installed and it does with me when VMware Workstation is the active window.

I would advise you upgrade to the latest version - VMware Workstation 6.5 should be a free upgrade for you.